# Updating a nested state in redux using Object.assign

Tags: reactjs, redux

My current state is :

**s1:**

```
[
{primaryKey : 123,
 otherKeys: value
:
otherkeys... 
},
{
 primaryKey : 345,
 otherKeys: value
 :
 :otherKeys...
},
{
primarykey : 567,
otherKeys...
},
{
primaryKey : 789,
otherKeys...
}
]
```

I want to update the elements at index 0 and index 1 with

**s2:**

```
[
{primaryKey : 123,
 updatedKeys: value
:
otherkeys... 
},
{
 primaryKey : 345,
 updatesKeys: value
 :
 :otherKeys...
}
]
```

After updating my state should look like this:

```
[
{primaryKey : 123,
 updatedKeys: value
:
otherkeys... 
},
{
 primaryKey : 345,
 updatedKeys: value
 :
 :otherKeys...
},
{
primarykey : 567,
otherKeys...
},
{
primaryKey : 789,
otherKeys...
}
]
```

I tried iterating over the state object and Object.assign to new Object on their primaryKey match.

```
state.map( (data1) =>{
    s2.map((data) => {
     if(data1.primaryKey === data.primaryKey){
       data1 = Object.assign({}, data);
     }
    })
})
```

I am confused, is there a better way to do this other than using map twice?

Answer (score 0):

For amending elements of an array, and ES6 syntax, the *spread* operator is pretty idiomatic:

```
var newArray = [
  ...list.slice(0, indexOfElement),
  amendedElement
  ...list.slice(indexOfElement+1)
];
```

So, you'd have to find the index of your element, create a clone and amend it and then return a new array constructed as above.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markwill/28voz94g/7/)

Watch this:

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread

it explains it brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to changing your data structure from an array of objects to an an object keyed by id then you are open simplifying your updates further.

Put simply: you use the primary key as the keyed id for wach of your elements.  This works much like the index of a normal array but means that you can replace the number with any valid identifier.

> Doing so would allow you to update your state by using:
>
> ```
> s1 = {
>   ...s1,
>   ...s2
> }
> ```

Changes you'd have to make to your state:

*Amend your current state s1 to:*

```
// it is now an object whose keys are now the primary key
{
  [123]{
    otherKeys: value
    :
    otherkeys... 
    },
  [345]{
     otherKeys: value
     :
     :otherKeys...
    },
  [567]{
    otherKeys...
    },
  [789]{
    otherKeys...
  }
}
```

*Amend your new s2 s follows:*

```
// again, it is now an object whose keys are now the primary key
{
  [123]{
    updatedKeys: value
    :
    otherkeys... 
  },
  [345]{
    updatedKeys: value
    :
    :otherKeys...
  }
}
```

Using the suggested spread syntax at the top you can update s1 with s2 to the following:

```
{
  [123]{
    updatedKeys: value
    :
    otherkeys... 
  },
  [345]{
    updatedKeys: value
    :
    :otherKeys...
  },
  [567]{
    otherKeys...
  },
  [789]{
    otherKeys...
  }
}
```

---

---

*In response to @nitte93user3232918's extra question in comments about **how to convert from s1 array of object to an object of objects**:*

```
let newS1 = {};
s1.map((val,i) => {
  newS1 = {
    ..s1,
    [val.primarykey]:val
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, to convert the the array into key value object, I am doing something like this.

       ` const newObj = s1.reduce((element, index) => {
          let obj = {
            index[primaryKey] : index
          }
          return {obj}
        }, {});`

But it says. `SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected` , for  `index[primaryKey] : index`. ANy idea?

Comment: You are programmatically trying to convert your original s1 into the format I suggested above?  You're effectiely having to take in the original s1 (an _array_ of objects) and create a _**new object**_ containing keyed id objects

Comment: Rather than include an reply in comments, I've added a solution for you in my answer in order to make the format more readable.Although technically this is an answer to a separate question completely.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.assign` should be a convenient way to do this.

If your state is in the form of an array this should be the best way:

```
var newState = Object.assign([], s1, s2);
```

This combines the updated state values of s2 into s1.

See this example: http://www.es6fiddle.net/ivxsln91/